# Istanbul: Ignore function or variable by name

Tags: testing, redux, code-coverage, istanbul

I'm looking for a way to globally ignore common functions in my project. For example in my React/Redux app I use functions mapDispatchToProps & mapStateToProps across multiple files and would like for coverage reports to always exclude these functions. Is there a global config of some sort I can utilize or do I need to add `/* istanbul ignore next */` before every instance every time?